# Overflow-x: scroll cuts off beginning of div

Tags: html, css

I have created this stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftv8ez

I'm running into this issue, where I have a container div with a fixed width (300px).

Within it, I have some box divs, also with a fixed width (300px).

The container div, has overflow-x: scroll, so the idea is that you can scroll the div if it ever overflows.

However, the result is not performing as expected. The beginning of the container div is cut short, which results in it not being possible to scroll the first box into view.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To fix it, you can change the .container justify-content value from `justify-content:center` to `justify-content:start`

Comment: that was my problem too but what if we do want it to be centered when the content fits (when no scroll is needed) ?

Comment: @raquelhortab I'm a few years late, but (at least nowadays) this can be achieved in all browsers - see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @raquelhortab, the [currently accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60945286/4602253) doesn't cover the case where we really do want the content to be centered in non-overflowing scenarios. For that, nowadays (and since 2018 in Firefox) there is the optional "overflow-position" parameter of the `justify-content` property, which optionally comes before the "content-position" (i.e. regular) value:

```
justify-content: safe center;
```

This way, overflowing content will be treated as if `justify-content` was set to start.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#safe

Comment: "The accepted solution" can change. You should reference _specific_ answers using the link provided on each.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your CSS. In the .Box you need to change height and width in .box or need to change width of scroll container because you Set size of 300px change it to 500 or less and you placed 4 colours of 100px now i corrected the code to 50px and it works.

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: That was the whole point though :D To have 4 boxes wider than the container, so I can get the scrollbar to display